# Kivy: Multiple Screens and Menu Items not impletmenting

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am very new in kivy and working on a simple application using python. I want to create an application in kivy which comprises of constant menu items on left pane and their respective screens on right big pane or screen. But I am unable to find the solution in kivy examples and also in youtube video tutorials and also in google. Please check my simple code and refer to some solution.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

#Code Starts here
Builder.load_string("""
#:import random random.random
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition


<MenuScreen>:
    hue: random()
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: self.hue, .5, .12
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: 'Home'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.95}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'home'
        on_release: root.manager.transition = NoTransition(duration=0)
    Button:
        text: 'Login History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.88}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'loginhistory'
        on_release: root.manager.transition = NoTransition(duration=0)
    Button:
        text: 'Alarm History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.81}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'alarmhistory'
        on_release: root.manager.transition = NoTransition(duration=0)
    Button:
        text: 'User Management'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.74}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'usermanagement'
        on_release: root.manager.transition = NoTransition(duration=0)
    Button:
        text: 'Call SoS'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.67}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callsos'
        on_release: root.manager.transition = NoTransition(duration=0)
    Button:
        text: 'Settings'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.60}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'settings'
        on_release: root.manager.transition = NoTransition(duration=0)
    Button:
        text: 'Call RealTec'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.53}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callrealtec'
        on_release: root.manager.transition = NoTransition(duration=0)
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .5, None
        height: 250
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        orientation: 'vertical'


<HomeScreen>:
    hue: random()
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: self.hue, .5, .2
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    Button:
        background_color: [1, 2, 1, 2]
        text: 'Home'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.95}
        size: 150, 50
    Button:
        text: 'Login History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.88}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'loginhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'Alarm History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.81}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'alarmhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'User Management'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.74}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'usermanagement'
    Button:
        text: 'Call SoS'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.67}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callsos'
    Button:
        text: 'Settings'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.60}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'settings'
    Button:
        text: 'Call RealTec'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.53}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callrealtec'
    Button:
        text: 'Main Menu'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.46}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'menu'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .5, None
        height: 250
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        orientation: 'vertical'

<LoginHistoryScreen>:
    hue: random()
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: self.hue, .5, .9
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: 'Home'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.95}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'home'
    Button:
        text: 'Login History'
        background_color: [1, 2, 1, 2]
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.88}
        size: 150, 50
    Button:
        text: 'Alarm History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.81}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'alarmhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'User Management'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.74}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'usermanagement'
    Button:
        text: 'Call SoS'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.67}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callsos'
    Button:
        text: 'Settings'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.60}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'settings'
    Button:
        text: 'Call RealTec'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.53}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callrealtec'
    Button:
        text: 'Main Menu'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.46}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'menu'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .5, None
        height: 250
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        orientation: 'vertical'


<AlarmHistoryScreen>:
    hue: random()
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: self.hue, .5, .6
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: 'Home'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.95}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'home'
    Button:
        text: 'Login History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.88}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'loginhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'Alarm History'
        background_color: [1, 2, 1, 2]
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.81}
        size: 150, 50
    Button:
        text: 'User Management'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.74}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'usermanagement'
    Button:
        text: 'Call SoS'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.67}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callsos'
    Button:
        text: 'Settings'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.60}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'settings'
    Button:
        text: 'Call RealTec'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.53}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callrealtec'
    Button:
        text: 'Main Menu'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.46}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'menu'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .5, None
        height: 250
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        orientation: 'vertical'

<UserManagementScreen>:
    hue: random()
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: self.hue, .5, .8
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: 'Home'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.95}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'home'
    Button:
        text: 'Login History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.88}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'loginhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'Alarm History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.81}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'alarmhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'User Management'
        background_color: [1, 2, 1, 2]
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.74}
        size: 150, 50
    Button:
        text: 'Call SoS'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.67}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callsos'
    Button:
        text: 'Settings'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.60}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'settings'
    Button:
        text: 'Call RealTec'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.53}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callrealtec'
    Button:
        text: 'Main Menu'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.46}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'menu'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .5, None
        height: 250
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        orientation: 'vertical'

<CallSoSScreen>:
    hue: random()
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: self.hue, .5, .7
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: 'Home'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.95}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'home'
    Button:
        text: 'Login History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.88}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'loginhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'Alarm History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.81}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'alarmhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'User Management'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.74}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'usermanagement'
    Button:
        text: 'Call SoS'
        background_color: [1, 2, 1, 2]
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.67}
        size: 150, 50
    Button:
        text: 'Settings'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.60}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'settings'
    Button:
        text: 'Call RealTec'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.53}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callrealtec'
    Button:
        text: 'Main Menu'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.46}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'menu'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .5, None
        height: 250
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        orientation: 'vertical'

<SettingsScreen>:
    hue: random()
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: self.hue, .5, .5
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: 'Home'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.95}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'home'
    Button:
        text: 'Login History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.88}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'loginhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'Alarm History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.81}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'alarmhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'User Management'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.74}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'usermanagement'
    Button:
        text: 'Call SoS'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.67}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callsos'
    Button:
        text: 'Settings'
        background_color: [1, 2, 1, 2]
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.60}
        size: 150, 50
    Button:
        text: 'Call RealTec'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.53}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callrealtec'
    Button:
        text: 'Main Menu'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.46}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'menu'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .5, None
        height: 250
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        orientation: 'vertical'

<CallRealTecScreen>:
    hue: random()
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: self.hue, .5, .4
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    Button:
        text: 'Home'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.95}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'home'
    Button:
        text: 'Login History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.88}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'loginhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'Alarm History'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.81}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'alarmhistory'
    Button:
        text: 'User Management'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.74}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'usermanagement'
    Button:
        text: 'Call SoS'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.67}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'callsos'
    Button:
        text: 'Settings'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.60}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'settings'
    Button:
        text: 'Call RealTec'
        background_color: [1, 2, 1, 2]
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.05, 'center_y':.53}
        size: 150, 50
    Button:
        text: 'Main Menu'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.05, 'center_y':0.46}
        size: 150, 50
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'menu'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: .5, None
        height: 250
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        orientation: 'vertical'


""")

# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    hue = NumericProperty(0)
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    hue = NumericProperty(0)
    pass

class LoginHistoryScreen(Screen):
    hue = NumericProperty(0)
    pass

class AlarmHistoryScreen(Screen):
    hue = NumericProperty(0)
    pass

class UserManagementScreen(Screen):
    hue = NumericProperty(0)
    pass

class CallSosScreen(Screen):
    hue = NumericProperty(0)
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    hue = NumericProperty(0)
    pass

class CallRealTecScreen(Screen):
    hue = NumericProperty(0)
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))
sm.add_widget(LoginHistoryScreen(name='loginhistory'))
sm.add_widget(AlarmHistoryScreen(name='alarmhistory'))
sm.add_widget(UserManagementScreen(name='usermanagement'))
sm.add_widget(CallSosScreen(name='callsos'))
sm.add_widget(CallRealTecScreen(name='callrealtec'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Please read our [ask] section. Blanket requests for code or code check are generally off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read through your code. You should be providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That said here's a short example that you can build upon. The main take away from the example, is that you don't have to add `ScreenManager` as a top level widget.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class Manager(ScreenManager):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Manager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(4):
            txt = 'Screen {}'.format(i)
            lbl = Label(text=txt)
            screen = Screen(name=txt)
            screen.add_widget(lbl)
            self.add_widget(screen)


class Nav(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, sm=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Nav, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sm = sm
        self.rows = 4
        self.size_hint = (.2, 1)
        for i in range(4):
            self.add_widget(Button(text="Screen {}".format(i), on_release=self.change))

    def change(self, btn):
        self.sm.current = btn.text


class Root(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Root, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.orientation = "horizontal"
        sm = Manager()

        self.add_widget(Nav(sm=sm))
        self.add_widget(sm)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(App):
        return Root()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. it works but how could I work on different screens (like text boxes, icons, etc on other screens which are switched to front). Can you help me if i work on screen1 it shows some objects in it and screen2 shows other objects and so forth.

Comment: You will want to create a new class based on `screen` then instantiate each screen so you can add/access properties and values of that object. Give it a shot and see what you can come up with. After, if you need help, it might be best to post a new question. [This](https://pythonprogramming.net/kivy-screen-manager-tutorial/) is a decent tutorial.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept my answer. Thanks!